# Can I use typecasts in C to get the size of memory at a pointer to an address?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm trying to use shared memory segments in POSIX and am having a lot of trouble figuring out if there is memory at a certain address.

I saw a solution that uses `file_size = *(size_t *)ptr`

Where ptr is the returned pointer from some call to `mmap (.... )`

I don't really understand how this works. What does `*(size_t *)` typecasting do? I assume it `(size_t)*var` would cast the value at pointer var to a `size_t` type. But then, when I put another asterisk... this would give me a pointer again, wouldn't it?

Comment: It reads the first `sizeof(size_t)` bytes at the memory location. If someone wrote the size of the memory block there, you can read it from the location.

Comment: you would use "&" to get the pointer. "*" deferences the pointer and gets your value.

Comment: @mch thanks for your response
So if I used *(int *)mem, this would read the first sizeof(int) bytes at the location?

Comment: You cannot test memory to see if it's there or not. You need to know by some other means.

Comment: @YoussefG. right but I was confused by the series of two asterisks. so I know (size_t *)ptr would be casting pointer into size_t value. However don't intuitively understand what the second asterisk does here

Comment: `(size_t *)ptr` casts `ptr` to a pointer to `size_t` (aka `size_t *`), the * before this expression dereference the pointer to get the value.

Comment: @mch wow that finally makes sense. thanks.

Comment: Actually its casting it to a "size *".  for example if your ptr was originally a (void *), it gives a type that can be derefenced.  it equivalent to declaring ptr like this: size_t * ptr;.  After that everything is like normal pointer ref/deref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *no* general way to determine the size of the allocated memory to which a given pointer points. or even whether it points to a valid object. There might be some system-specific ways to determine something similar, but they're likely to be unreliable -- and they can't determine that a pointer points to a valid object, but not to the one that it's supposed to point to.

You'll just have to keep careful track of this information yourself.

The method you describe:

```
file_size = *(size_t *)ptr;
```

can work *if* the memory happens to have been allocated by something that specifically stores the size at the beginning of the allocated region -- but only if you already know that `ptr` is valid.

`ptr` could be a pointer of any type (other than a function pointer). The cast `(size_t *)` *converts* the value of `ptr` so you can treat it as a pointer to a `size_t` object (`size_t` is an unsigned integer type used to represent sizes).  Dereferencing that `size_t*` value with the `*` dereference operator gives you the value of the `size_t` object.

Here's an example of a hypothetical allocation function that might work this way:

```
void *allocate(size_t size) {
    void *result = malloc(sizeof (size_t) + size);
    if (result != NULL) {
        *(size_t*)result = size;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and a function that gives you the currently allocated size:

```
size_t curr_size(void *ptr) {
    return *(size_t*)ptr;
}
```

**NOTE** that this ignores alignment issues. If you're allocating memory for something that requires stricter alignment that `size_t` does, this can fail badly.